# Combine items in array by their key

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js

I am using Ember Data to get some items for a cart. These items may look something like this

```
[
  {
    "item_id":"5635",
    "raffle_purchase_id":"1060",
    "item_name":"***",
    "item_desc":"***",
    "item_image":"5635-Ilbt8xNGsD-cropped.png",
    "item_amt":"2",
    "item_type":"raffle"
  },
  {
    "item_id":"5635",
    "raffle_purchase_id":"1061",
    "item_name":"***",
    "item_desc":"***",
    "item_image":"5635-Ilbt8xNGsD-cropped.png",
    "item_amt":"4",
    "item_type":"raffle"
  },
  {
    "item_id":"5635",
    "raffle_purchase_id":"1563",
    "item_name":"***",
    "item_desc":"***",
    "item_image":"5635-Ilbt8xNGsD-cropped.png",
    "item_amt":"2",
    "item_type":"raffle"
  },
  ...
]
```

Each item here has a different purchase ID that I need to update on the server side so I need to send back all the items to update back to the server. However when I'm displaying these I don't want to show every line of this same purchase over and over again. Rather I want to combine those and calculate the total those purchases cost.

Each item has an item ID, in this case those are the same for these 3 (and potentially more) items, and there might be a handful of other purchases of the same item multiple times that I want to do the same thing to.

Basically I need to get all the items here that have the same ID, get a total sum of their `item_amt` property, and then combine them and show just one line item with the total.

I'm a little lost on this one as to where to start and where to do this. Currently this return is coming from the route in the model hook so I know I can do whatever processing I need to before actually setting the model. However I want to make sure I keep the original items intact (as I will need to know the unique `raffle_purchase_id`'s) for later when the user is paying for these.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a `for` loop to go through the array and add all of the items with the same `purchase_id` as some hardcoded parameter to another array, and then loop through the new array and find the sum of the `item_amt` of each of them by adding that value to a variable `sum`?

Comment: That's my first thought so far, seems messy but for now it may have to do, I imagine there may be a more convenient way but maybe not.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop over them and put the sums in a map, mapped by their item_id:

```
var returnedJSON = [
{
    "item_id":"5635",
    "raffle_purchase_id":"1060",
    "item_name":"***",
    "item_desc":"***",
    "item_image":"5635-Ilbt8xNGsD-cropped.png",
    "item_amt":"2",
    "item_type":"raffle"
  },
  {
    "item_id":"5635",
    "raffle_purchase_id":"1061",
    "item_name":"***",
    "item_desc":"***",
    "item_image":"5635-Ilbt8xNGsD-cropped.png",
    "item_amt":"4",
    "item_type":"raffle"
  },
  {
    "item_id":"5635",
    "raffle_purchase_id":"1563",
    "item_name":"***",
    "item_desc":"***",
    "item_image":"5635-Ilbt8xNGsD-cropped.png",
    "item_amt":"2",
    "item_type":"raffle"
  }
];
var itemTotals = {};
for(var i = 0; i < returnedJSON.length; i++) {
  if(!itemTotals[returnedJSON[i].item_id]) {
   itemTotals[returnedJSON[i].item_id] = 0;
  }
  itemTotals[returnedJSON[i].item_id] += Number(returnedJSON[i].item_amt);
}
```

[Working CodePen](http://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/MKGKap) look at the console to see value of map

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and collect all sums in an object:

```js
var data = [{ "item_id": "5635", "raffle_purchase_id": "1060", "item_name": "***", "item_desc": "***", "item_image": "5635-Ilbt8xNGsD-cropped.png", "item_amt": "2", "item_type": "raffle" }, { "item_id": "5635", "raffle_purchase_id": "1061", "item_name": "***", "item_desc": "***", "item_image": "5635-Ilbt8xNGsD-cropped.png", "item_amt": "4", "item_type": "raffle" }, { "item_id": "5635", "raffle_purchase_id": "1563", "item_name": "***", "item_desc": "***", "item_image": "5635-Ilbt8xNGsD-cropped.png", "item_amt": "2", "item_type": "raffle" }, ],
    sum = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a.item_id] = (r[a.item_id] || 0) + +a.item_amt;
        return r;
    }, {});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(sum, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a map reduce or get clever but something like this is simple enough and seems to work:

```
var processed = {};
items.forEach(function(item) {
    if(!processed.item_id) {
        processed.item_id = {
            item_id: item.item_id,
            item_amt: 0
        }
    }
    processed.item_id.item_amt += parseInt(item.item_amt);
});
```